# Do prime pairs inbetween and equidistant from adjacent integer powers cover all the prime numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that every odd prime number is a member of one or more pairs of primes $(p_1, p_2)$ such that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are inbetween and equidistant from two adjacent powers of some number $n$? i.e.

$0 < p_1 - n^m = n^{m+1} - p_2 $ for some positive integers $n, m$

For example the prime number $73$ is a member of the pair $(73, 179)$ where $73 - 6^2 = 6^3 - 179$

Comment: Your equations should be $|p_1-n^m|=d$ and $|p_2-n^{m+1}|=d$ to reflect the opening sentence.

Comment: Is $\ n\ $ fixed or variable?

Comment: @Wlod AA n,m, and d can be any positive integers, chosen for each p

Comment: Thank you (for     being arbitrary; and is  a user variable? :) ). #### What would be your numerical evidence?

Comment: You may say "odd prime".

Comment: This boils down to finding a primality radius $r$ of $q:=\frac{n^{m+1}+n^{m}}{2}$ less than $l:=n^{m+1}-q$, which should exist provided $n$ is large enough, under a sufficiently strong form of Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Where a primality radius of an integer $u$ is a non negative intever $v$ such that both $u+v$ and $u-v$ are primes.

Comment: However, this question is of a different character. Goldbach's conjecture asks for one prime pair for 2n for every n, whereas this asks if every prime is part of a special pair for certain n.  It is unclear that one statement follows from the other.  Gerhard "Making An Unusual Pair Indeed" Paseman, 2020.05.10.

Comment: One could study first $\ \rho(a\ b)\ :=\ \{(p\ q)\in\Bbb P^2: p+q=a+b\ \text{and}\ a\le p\le\frac{a+b}2\}\ $ for every $\ (a\ b)\in\Bbb Z\ $ such that $\ 0<a<b-1.$

Answer (score 2):

For every odd prime $\ p,\ $ and for every integer $\ n>1\ $ there exists exactly one positive integer $\ m=\mu(p\ n)\ $ such that
$$ n^m\ <\ p\ \le\ n^{m+1}. $$

> Odd prime $\ p\ $ is said to be $\ n$-*doubtful* (or $n$-*questionable*) $\,\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\,\ q:=n^m+n^{m+1}-p\,\ $
>   is not a prime, where $\ m=\mu(p\ n).$
>
> Odd prime $\ p\ $ is *trustful* $\,\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\,\ $ there exists integer $\ n>1\ $ such that $\ p\ $ is not $n$-doubtful. Otherwise, $p$ *mistrusted*.

The OP's conjecture (actually a question) was that every odd prime is trusted.

## ==============================================

The first $2$-questionable prime is $\ p=23\ $ because

$$ 2^4 < p\ < 2^5 $$

and

$$ q\ :=\ 2^4+2^5\ -\ p\ =\ 25 = 5^2 $$

is not a prime. Thus, there remains to verify primality (or non-primality) of

$$ n^m + n^{m+1} - 23  $$

just for a very limited number of cases, for all $\ n>2\ $ such that $\ n<23$:

- $\ 3^2<23<3^3\ $ -- well, $\ 13+23=36=3^2+3^3\ $ and $\ q:=23\ $ is a prime hence the conjecture holds.

The next $2$-questionable prime is $\ 41.\ $ However,

$$ 67\ =\ 3^3+3^4-41 $$

is a prime. The conjecture holds for $\ p:=41.$

There is just one more $2$-questionable prime in the
$\ [2^5;2^6]\ $ range, namely $\ p:=47.\ $ But $\ 47\ $ is not $3$-doubtful -- indeed:

$$ 61\ = 3^3+3^4-47\ $$

is a prime. Next, we get a $2$-doubtful prime $\ 127\ $ from the higher end of of $\ [2^6;2^7].\ $ It's not $3$-doubtful though:

$$ 197\ =\ 3^4+3^5-127 $$

is a prime.

Given a huge list of consecutive primes, a computer program can verify the conjecture quickly within the given range of primes.

I am still curious about the smallest prime that is both $2$- and $3$-doubtful, as well as about

> the general question about prime $\ d_n\ $ which is the smallest among $k$-doubtful for every $\ k\le n.$

**REMARK** doubtful = questionable (*but of course* :) ).

Actually:

**The smallest** $2$- and $3$-questionable prime is $\ p:=73.$

**Indeed**,
$$ 119 = 2^6+2^7-73 $$
is not a prime ($119=7\cdot 17$) hence prime $73$ is $2$-questionable. Also,
$$ 35 = 3^3+3^4-73 $$
is not a prime hence prime $73$ is $3$-questionable. **Great!***

Furthermore, the same prime $\ p:=73\ $ is also $4$-questionable
since

$$ 247 = 4^3+4^4-73 $$

is not a prime $\ (247=13\cdot 19),\ $ as well as $5$-questionable:

$$ 77 = 5^2+5^3-73 $$

is not prime. Thus,

**Prime** $\,73\ $ is the smallest that is $2$- and $3$- and $4$-questionable. Furthermore, **prime** $\,73\ $ is the smallest that is $2$- and $3$- and $4$- and $5$-questionable.

**However**, the conjecture holds for prime $73$ since it is not $6$-questionable; **indeed**:

$$ 179 = 6^2+6^3-73 $$
is a prime.

Comment: It's interesting that you're hitting with such small numbers - mostly $2$s and a few $3$s. The overall asymptotic situation is good but I wouldn't expect you to hit so fast so often.